# Command 'python' and 'pip' not found after activating pyenv-virtualenv

Tags: python, pyenv-virtualenv

Everything is going smooth including activating a created pyenv-virtualenv.
But when I execute 'python' or 'pip' it doesn't work and outputs the following results:

```
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$ python test.py

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
```

The foremost `(value)` means that my environment is activated, and I also print the command `pyenv versions`. The output is as follows:

```
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.7.6
  3.7.6/envs/value
* value (set by /data/cz/workspace/value/.python-version)
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
```

I am sure that I have correctly configured my ~/.bashrc file:

```
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$ tail -3 ../../.bashrc
export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
```

Then I found executable `python` and `pip` exist in the corresponding directory:

```
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$ ll ~/.pyenv/versions/value/bin/
total 56
drwxrwxr-x 2 cz cz 4096 Mar 20 20:32 ./
drwxrwxr-x 5 cz cz 4096 Mar 20 16:30 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 cz cz 2223 Mar 20 16:30 activate
-rw-r--r-- 1 cz cz 1275 Mar 20 16:30 activate.csh
-rw-r--r-- 1 cz cz 2427 Mar 20 16:30 activate.fish
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  272 Mar 20 16:30 easy_install*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  272 Mar 20 16:30 easy_install-3.7*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  258 Mar 20 20:32 f2py*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  258 Mar 20 20:32 f2py3*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  258 Mar 20 20:32 f2py3.7*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  254 Mar 20 16:30 pip*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  254 Mar 20 16:30 pip3*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  254 Mar 20 16:30 pip3.7*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cz cz  113 Mar 20 16:30 pydoc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cz cz    9 Mar 20 16:30 python -> python3.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cz cz    9 Mar 20 16:30 python3 -> python3.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 cz cz   44 Mar 20 16:30 python3.7 -> /data/cz/.pyenv/versions/3.7.6/bin/python3.7*
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
```

and when I use the above executable `pip` and `python`, it works successfully:

```
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$ ~/.pyenv/versions/value/bin/pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
numpy      1.21.5
pip        19.2.3
scipy      1.7.3
setuptools 41.2.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$ ~/.pyenv/versions/value/bin/python test.py
KstestResult(statistic=0.2222222222222222, pvalue=0.9944055944055944)
KstestResult(statistic=0.2222222222222222, pvalue=0.9944055944055944)
KstestResult(statistic=0.539827837277029, pvalue=0.423516838690273)
(value) cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~/workspace/value$
```

How could I issue the question Command 'python' and 'pip' not found?

Comment: Q1. Did you source .bashrc after you added that line in?

Comment: Yes, I sourced.

Comment: You added ~/.pyenv/bin to the PATH but the binaries are in ~/.pyenv/versions/value/bin/

Comment: Yes, and I'll show you my PATH: 
`cz@iZj6ce3j6ldxwyg2tjixztZ:~$ echo $PATH$
/data/cz/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:~/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin$
`

Comment: I meant your path says to look for apps in  ~/.pyenv/bin but your apps (ie. python and pip) are actually in ~/.pyenv/versions/value/bin/ . Not sure why this is the case as I dont really use pyenv. So either add ~/.pyenv/versions/value/bin/ to your path or rename ~/.pyenv/versions/value/bin/ to be ~/.pyenv/bin/ . I suspect your pyenv was installed incorrectly, but is just a guess.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are indeed some bugs. I found something in pyenv's official document(https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). It lies a title named 'Understanding Shims': "Pyenv works by inserting a directory of shims at the front of your PATH", e.g., `$(pyenv root)/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`. Then I add `(pyenv root)/shims:` in the front of my PATH, and pyenv works successfully.

Comment: 'Advanced Configuration' in the above link says that the code `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"` helps set up your shims path. Whereas `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` doesn't take this effect, which is exactly written in my bash file. I removed `(pyenv root)/shims:` and changed `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to `eval "$(pyenv init --path)"`, and my issue is also solved.

Comment: `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` helps autocompletion, shims rehash, and pyenv's shell function. We'd better add it to bash file. So I add both init codes to my bash file finally, i.e., `export PATH="~/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"`